# Creating a bitmap with a specific format in order to invert/mirror it

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm using the following method to create an inverted bitmap:

```
HBITMAP CreateMirroredBitmap( HBITMAP hbmOrig)
{
    HDC hdc, hdcMem1, hdcMem2;
    HBITMAP hbm = NULL, hOld_bm1, hOld_bm2;
    BITMAP bm;
    if (!hbmOrig)
        return NULL;
    if (!GetObject(hbmOrig, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm))
        return NULL;

    // Grab the screen DC.
    hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (hdc)
    {
        hdcMem1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        if (!hdcMem1)
        {
            ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
            return NULL;
        }
        hdcMem2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        if (!hdcMem2)
        {
            DeleteDC(hdcMem1);
            ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
            return NULL;
        }
        hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight);
        if (!hbm)
        {
            ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem1);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem2);
            return NULL;
        }
        // Flip the bitmap.
        hOld_bm1 = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem1, hbmOrig);
        hOld_bm2 = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem2 , hbm );
        SetLayout(hdcMem2, LAYOUT_RTL);
        BitBlt(hdcMem2, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem1, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hdcMem1, hOld_bm1 );
        SelectObject(hdcMem1, hOld_bm2 );
        DeleteDC(hdcMem1);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem2);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    }
    return hbm;
}
```

Taken from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688119

The problem is regardless of what bitmap I use for input (8, 16 or 32bit colors) it will always output 32bit bitmap. My guess is that CreateCompatibleBitmap creates the default 32bit bitmap because the DC that I'm passing is screen's DC which is 32bit.
Is there any way to mirror the bitmap but also retain its color depth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateBitmap` and `CreateDIBSection` will create you bitmap of requested bitness, and you still can select them with a DC to receive result to.